# specify minimum length of a textbox in ionic2 with angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm validating a textbox with angular2 which works fine. Now I'm trying to set a minimum set of characters to be entered in the textbox but when I try I get this error:

```
Expected validator to return a Promise or Observable
```

Below is my script

```
customerNumber: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public viewctrl: ViewController,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              public http: Http,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

                this.verifyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  customerNumber: ['', Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]
                });
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-input type="text" formControlName="customerNumber" placeholder="Enter your Customer Number"  [(ngModel)]="customerNumber"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
customerNumber: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public viewctrl: ViewController,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              public http: Http,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

                this.verifyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  customerNumber: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])]
                });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you're passing `Validators.minLength(5)` as third parameter which is a async validators

it should be

```
this.verifyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  customerNumber: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]]
                });
```